# Title on a UIButton truncates

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I've set a UIButton as the titleView of my navigation bar. However the title seems to truncate no matter how wide the button is. Why?

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:[[NSDate date] stringWithNSDateFormatterMediumStyle] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40)];
self.navigationItem.titleView = button;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 40)];  // are you sure your button is wide enough?
```

Comment: Absolutely. No matter how wide I make it always truncates!

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's probably a limitation being imposed by the nav bar.  Can you use a shorter format like 12/25/11 or a smaller font?

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing.